# Powershell not always running ScriptsToProcess on import

Tags: powershell

After using `Install-Module` to install `powershell-yaml` I had about a week of use before I came in one morning to it not loading `YamlDotNet` properly.

Now if I try to use `ConvertFrom-Yaml` before manually running `Import-Module powershell-yaml` I get the the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\user> "---" | ConvertFrom-Yaml
New-Object : Cannot find type [YamlDotNet.RepresentationModel.YamlStream]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\powershell-yaml\0.3.1\powershell-yaml.psm1:24 char:23
+ ...  $yamlStream = New-Object "YamlDotNet.RepresentationModel.YamlStream"
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\powershell-yaml\0.3.1\powershell-yaml.psm1:25 char:9
+         $yamlStream.Load([System.IO.TextReader] $stringReader)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Previously (and on most systems) this worked fine. If I run a manual `Import-Module` before calling the function it works fine:

```
PS C:\Users\user> Import-Module powershell-yaml
PS C:\Users\user> "---" | ConvertFrom-Yaml

PS C:\Users\user>
```

Both my and a coworker's machines started this behavior at about the same time. This morning my system started working properly again, but his is still exhibiting the behavior. We haven't been able to duplicate it on other machines.

I've narrowed it down to a script referenced in `Powershell-Yaml` manifest's  `ScriptsToProcess` not being called during autoload, but runs fine during a manual `Import-Module`. On working machines the script in `ScriptsToProcess` is run in both cases. As a workaround we can force a module load by putting an `Import-Module` in our profile, ideally we'd like to find a root cause.

`Import-Module -Verbose` doesn't help, because calling `Import-Module` first always works.

Comment: It's possible that auto-loading just doesn't run those scripts.  Are you using absolute paths in `ScriptsToProcess`?

Comment: Powershell-YAML uses relative paths in the `ScriptsToProcess`, but that doesn't seem to be the problem. On the errant machines it doesn't even attempt to load it at all. On working machines it loads just fine automagically with a relative path.

Comment: [Here's an interesting article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/02/20/powertip-turn-off-powershell-module-autoload/).  I'd suggest checking auto-loading is enabled.

Comment: I had high hopes when seeing there was a config param that controls it, but alas all our machines (working and not) have that var undefined. Since my initial post my machine is back to not working without even so much as a reboot.